# Should there be an 'cpp-indices-trick' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Every once in a while, questions pop up that essentially ask for the [Modern-C++ indices trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463388/can-someone-please-explain-the-indices-trick) - mostly implicitly, since people don't know that's what they need/want. Here's a very recent example:

[How do I get index of elements in parameter pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058194/how-do-i-get-index-of-elements-in-parameter-pack/)

I was wondering if this issue shouldn't have its own tag (`indices-trick` or `cpp-indices-trick`). It seems to me a much better choice than the c++11 or c++14 tag people often give these questions. It's related to variadic templates, which appear in c++11, but index-sequences are C++14 as far as the standard library; and then again, they can be implemented in C++11.

Answer (score 6):

It might be useful as an *answer*, but I don't see it holding much value as a tag.  It sounds like this "indices trick" is more about a solution than an actual subject matter, and thus, adding a tag for it would not be the best option here.

Comment: The thing is, it's essentially the only solution to a certain category of questions, which in many senses are just different forms of the same question.

Comment: It's still a *solution*.  It's not an actual question which is phrased; it's used as part of an answer to certain questions.  The fact that it's a solution in my mind makes it less desirable for tagging.

Comment: even if it is useful/educational for people to mind the associated and relatedness of all those questions?

Comment: **It's still describing a solution**.  There exists no mechanism to tag *answers*.  If the question can be answered by this, then it would be useful then to invest energy into creating a canonical answer with which other questions can be closed as a duplicate against.

Comment: Apparently, it's the community's opinion that [answer-based tags are ok](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26913/should-i-retag-a-question-with-a-tag-that-is-based-on-the-answer-and-not-the-que).